# Variadic Templates pack expansions

Tags: c++, c++11, parameters, variadic-templates, pack-expansion

In [Andrei's talk on GoingNative 2012](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Variadic-Templates-are-Funadic) he talks about Variadic Templates, and he explains at one point by way of the example underneath how the parameter pack expansions work.  Being fairly new to this subject I found it fairly hard to follow how each case works, could anybody please explain how the expansion works in each function call of `gun`?

```
template<class... Ts> void fun(Ts... vs) {
    gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...);
    gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...));
    gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to specify that `Ts` is (for example) `void*, int, char, std::string` or something, so the answers align a little better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1.

```
   gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...)
=> gun(A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::hun(vs)...)
=> gun(A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::hun(v1),
       A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::hun(v2),
       …,
       A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::hun(vm))
```

2.

```
   gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...))
=> gun(A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::hun(vs...))
=> gun(A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::hun(v1, v2, …, vm))
```

This should be obvious.

3.

```
   gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...)
=> gun(A<T1>::hun(v1), A<T2>::hun(v2), …, A<Tn>::hun(vn))
```

(In this case the program won't compile if the lengths of Ts and vs differ)

---

The `...` will expand a pattern (which includes any parameter packs) preceding it, meaning that, in `foo(Ts, Us, Vs)...`, each member of the list `Ts`, `Us`, `Vs` (enumerated in lock step) will be substituted into that pattern, and a comma separated list will be formed:

```
   foo(Ts, Us, Vs)...
=> foo(T1, U1, V1), foo(T2, U2, V2), …, foo(Tn, Un, Vn)
```

And if there are nested expansions, the innermost patterns will be expanded first. Therefore, in case 1, the pattern `Ts` will first be expanded into `T1, T2, …, Tn`. And then, the pattern preceding the outer `...` is `A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::fun(vs)` — note that `Ts` has been expanded — so it will be expanded to `A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::fun(v1), A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::fun(v2), …, A<T1, T2, …, Tn>::fun(vm)` by substituting `v1`, `v2`, etc. into `vs`.

Comment: The lengths of `Ts` and `vs` _can't_ differ.  That's like saying it won't compile if `5` is more than one `int`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The lengths are the same only because the function is declared as `template<class... Ts> void fun(Ts... vs)`. What if one declares another `template<class... Ts, class... Us> void iun(Us... vs)` :p

Comment: @KennyTM: Template parameter pack must be the last template argument otherwise it cannot be deduced or specified (14.1.11).

Answer (score 5):

KennyTM's answer is perfect.  I just also like samples.  But since his answer is abstract, I didn't feel like adding demos to his answer is the correct thing.  So demos for his answer are here.  I'm assuming his answer is right, I know nothing myself.  (If you upvote this, upvote his too)

Obviously this is all psudocode just showing the expanded states.

```
void foo<void*,int,char,std::string>(nullptr, 32, '7', "BANANA") {
    //gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs)...);
    gun(A<void*,int,char,std::string>::hun(nullptr)
       ,A<void*,int,char,std::string>::hun(32)
       ,A<void*,int,char,std::string>::hun('7')
       ,A<void*,int,char,std::string>::hun("BANANA")
       );
    //gun(A<Ts...>::hun(vs...));
    gun(A<void*,int,char,std::string>::hun(nullptr, 32, '7', "BANANA");
    //gun(A<Ts>::hun(vs)...);
    gun(A<void*>::hun(nullptr)
       ,A<int>::hun(32),
       ,A<char>::hun('7'),
       ,A<std::string>::hun("BANANA")
       );
}
```

Comment: oh hey!  I just found the slide this question came from!

Comment: Using `NULL` with variadic templates?  That's like using a Ferrari to pull a trailer ;)