# variadic templates: invalid use of void expression

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to create a generic collection for events so that it'll be reusable for different kind of event-sets. While playing around with variadic templates, I came across [THIS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9650857), which helped me for my example here:

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

namespace
{
struct Event3 {
    static const int event_type = 3;
    int a;
};

struct Event5 {
    static const int event_type = 5;
    double d;
};

struct Event7 {
    static const int event_type = 7;
    std::string s;
};


template <class ...K>
void gun(K...) {}

template <class... Ts>
class EventCollection
{
    template <typename T>
    void update_map(std::unordered_map<int, size_t> & map, const T &)
    {
        BOOST_CHECK(map.find(T::event_type) == map.end());
        map[T::event_type] = sizeof(T);
    }


public:
    std::unordered_map<int, size_t> curr_map;

    EventCollection(Ts... ts)
    {
        gun(update_map(curr_map, ts)...); // will expand for each input type
    }
};

} // namespace

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test_01 )
{
    Event3 x{13};
    Event5 y{17.0};
    Event7 z{"23"};

    EventCollection<Event3, Event5, Event7> hoshi(x, y, z);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(hoshi.curr_map.size(), 3);
}
```

However, the line

```
gun(update_map(curr_map, ts)...); // will expand for each input type
```

gives me an 'error: invalid use of void expression'.
Can anybody tell me, how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `update_map` returns `void`. Hence you cannot write this:

```
gun(update_map(curr_map, ts)...);
```

because the return values of `update_map` is supposed to be passed to `gun` as arguments.

The fix is to pass something to `gun` as argument, so you can do this:

```
gun( (update_map(curr_map, ts),0)...);
```

Now the expresssion `(update_map(curr_map, ts),0)` turns out to be `0` which is passed as argument to `gun`. That should work. You can think of this as:

```
T argmument = (update_map(curr_map, ts),0);  //argument is 0, and T is int
```

--

Also, as the other answer pointed out that the order of evaluation of arguments to `gun()` are unspecified (means the order in which the function `update_map` is called, is unspecified) which may lead to undesired result. The other solution has given a solution to this problem. Here is another one (which is a bit tricky and easy!):

```
//ensure that the size of the below array is at least one.
int do_in_order[] = {0, (update_map(curr_map, ts),0)...};
```

Because the order of initialization of array elements are well-defined (from left-to-right), now all the calls to `update_map` happens in well-defined order.

Comment: I believe he would rather have `(update_map(curr_map, ts),ts)...`

Answer (score 0):

`update_map` is a function that returns void.

That line consists of calling `update_map`, and then passing the return value to `gun`.

You cannot pass a `void` return value to another function.

Hence "invalid use of void expression".

There are many ways to fix this, including having `update_map` return `struct empty {};`

Note that your code results in the calls of `update_map` happening in an unspecified order.  This can easily lead to unexpected behavior.

Might I suggest:

```
void do_in_order();
template<typename F0, typename... Functors>
void do_in_order( F0&& f0, Functors&& funcs... ) {
  f0();
  do_in_order( std::forward<Functors>(funcs)... );
}
```

then replace the call to `gun` with:

```
do_in_order([&]{update_map(curr_map, ts);}...); // will expand for each input type
```

which packages up the things to do into lambdas, which are then called in order that they are passed.

Now, this also does away with the need for an `update_map` function entirely:

```
do_in_order([&]{
  BOOST_CHECK(curr_map.find(ts::event_type) == curr_map.end());
  map[ts::event_type] = sizeof(ts);
}...);
```

which is awesome.

Comment: nice tip, but I don't really need the ordering (but I need different input types or more precisely: different event_types - maybe I should use a return of map_update to check that)

Comment: I think that is overkill. To enforce well-defined order, you can use array-initialization trick, as shown in my answer. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz except every time you do that, you have to say "I am doing this in order to enforce in-order evaluation of the tasks" in a comment.  The `do_in_order` function both says what it does and then does it.  The `forget` solution uses `int forget[]=` boilerplate, and `(X,0)` boilerplate, a total of 11 non-documenting boilerplate characters (+6 for `forget`), while `do_in_order` uses 8 non-documenting boilerplate characters (+11 for `do_in_order`).  It is lighter weight, once the `do_in_order` has been written once! :) And I challenge you to find a situation where it will run slower.

Comment: @Yakk: Is `int do_in_order[] = {(update_map(curr_map, ts),0)...};` better?

Comment: @Nawaz at least it is correct and does not fail for zero size event collections.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Alright. Here you go : `int do_in_order[] = {0, (update_map(curr_map, ts),0)...};`. Fixed?

Comment: @Nawaz Too heavyweight: you just added more boilerplate!  Plus, still fragile -- if `update_map` returns a type that overloads `operator,`, you no longer have an ordering guarantee.  So you need another 6 characters of boilerplate to deal with that issue..  And even without that, the solution is just hackey: creating an array for no purpose other than exploiting ordering guarantees?  If there was no other solution, I'd go for it. Meanwhile, take a look at the newest `do_in_order` use above -- I removed `update_map`, and `do_in_order` solution now takes fewer characters than the unordered sltn!